# Why is eval not working with command substitution?

Tags: linux, unix, shell-scripting

I have this command

```
$("${DIR}/test.py" "$1")
```

the output of which is

```
export SOME_VAR="hello world" export ANOTHER_VAR="hello"
```

But `eval $("${DIR}/test.py" "$1")`

seems to do nothing. What am I doing wrong?

I want to export those variables in my shell script.

Comment: did you mean that the output of `${DIR}/test.py" "$1"` is "export..."?

Comment: @niry yes the output is export .....

Comment: then try without eval, or without $()

Comment: neither would work. Without eval, i get the output i posted above. With $() I wont get command substitution and hence just get the same output i posted above. I want to "evaluate" that output too in my script.

Comment: Are you using bash? top line has `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: I tried using both `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/bin/sh`  same result. i am on bash3.2

Comment: trying to export to current shell so other programs can use these vars

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85941/discussion-between-niry-and-masterpiece).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, we determined that the problem was not using `source` to allow exporting vars to the current shell.